# com.apple.WebKit.WebContent spawns itself periodically stealing focus

Tags: keyboard, safari, x11

Ever since I switched to Mavericks I experience a problem with keyboard focus when using X11 based apps (that's at least how it manifests)

I have narrowed it down to Safari's com.apple.WebKit.WebContent process launched for every tab. It periodically (every ~60 seconds) seems to spawn itself launching another WebContent process for a couple of seconds before terminating, and in the process stealing the focus from X11.

This happens even without an open tab. I have removed ALL but three plugins and disabled all extensions.

Not only does this behavior make working with X11 based apps if not impossible but annoying at least, now I am wondering why Safari would be launching WebContent processes by itself.

Does anybody know what is going on?

(as reference I included https://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac/ticket/58 which has a link to a very interesting python script that monitors every focus change)

Comment: I just found a post talking about enabling the Debug menu in Safari, which in turn allowed to disable the launch of separate WebContent Processes per tab. This can also be achieved by `defaults write com.apple.Safari DebugDisablePerTabWebProcesses 1` and I have not seen a stolen focus since